# Vegas.js issue with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using the Vegas.js plugin tied to Jquery to generate my backgroundimages on my homepage, however, I encounter a problem once i go scrolling with the mousewheel in Internet Explorer.

See here: http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/Joost/

It works fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but when I scroll with the mousewheel in Internet Explorer (in IE 11 this is), a slight offset happens and the image returns than to its original position, as it is forced. When I use the side bar and scroll down, it works just fine and doesn't move at all.

Now I can solve this issue by removing the Javascript completely and change the CSS of my HTML, because its just a single image, but I'd like to know if there is an awnser for this, because I am planning on using multiple pictures.

Since I am not that familiair with JavaScript and Jquery, I read somewhere that IE is not so unforgiven as the rest of the browser when it comes to missplaced comma's or any other small error. However, after running over the code, it doesnt seem to have an error in it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vegas.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.vegas({
            src:'images/Sunset.jpg'
        });
        $.vegas('overlay', {
            src:'overlays/01.png'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your html?

Comment: the doctype was specified yes. I never solved the issue, and just decided to use a single background, with an extra css overlay. I pulled the website offline long ago anyway, it was juts a play site to learn some js.

Comment: surprisingly, it worked for me on IE11 after adding the Nicescroll jQuery plugin (https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com) to my page.